Top 20 paths sorted by latency in Grafana
I am using Grafana v10.4.1 (d94d597d84) set up on k8s.
I am trying to see the top 20 paths sorted by latency. I am having troubles using sort_desc and topk. It’s not working, the results it shows are not sorted and not showing 20 top results but more.
I am using bar gauge visualization. I’m using Loki as a datasource.
Here’s the query I am using:
sort_desc(topk(20, sum by(path_endpoint) (rate({namespace=~"$namespace", stream=~"$stream", container=~"$container"} | json |= $query| path_endpoint =~.+| path_endpoint !~/api/internal.+| path_endpoint !~/ws | __error__=`` | unwrap latency [5m]))))

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Try rearranging your query as below.
topk(20, sum by(path_endpoint) (rate({namespace=~"$namespace", stream=~"$stream", container=~"$container"} | json |= $query| path_endpoint =~.+| path_endpoint !~/api/internal.+| path_endpoint !~/ws | __error__=`` | unwrap latency [5m])))
| sort_desc

